# Android LibGDX: Cannot Load Image Dependancies

Tags: java, android, eclipse, png, libgdx

I am trying to run my game on the Android device, but once it gets into the main game, it stops because of an asset error: it cannot load a .png image, and also cannot load the dependency of that image. I do not understand what is happening here.

Image in question is here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Ih7ajWQd1EVGFJWWltSDJlUW8/edit?usp=sharing

Complete error log below:

```
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 949
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: data/monsters/plant/gas_cloud.png
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:517)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:351)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.finishLoading(AssetManager.java:372)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at dev.Manager.loadArtAssets(Manager.java:123)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at game.TheDevice.create(TheDevice.java:68)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at menu.StateManager.moveToGame(StateManager.java:137)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at game.Storyboard.advanceScene(Storyboard.java:59)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at game.Storyboard.update(Storyboard.java:50)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at game.Storyboard.render(Storyboard.java:79)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at menu.StateManager.render(StateManager.java:85)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:487)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: data/monsters/plant/gas_cloud.png
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:119)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:89)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:454)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:349)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    ... 11 more
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/monsters/plant/gas_cloud.png
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncResult.get(AsyncResult.java:46)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:117)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    ... 14 more
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/monsters/plant/gas_cloud.png
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureLoader.loadAsync(TextureLoader.java:72)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureLoader.loadAsync(TextureLoader.java:41)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:69)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:65)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: data/monsters/plant/gas_cloud.png (Internal)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:74)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:563)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.length(AndroidFileHandle.java:162)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:218)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    ... 10 more
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/monsters/plant/gas_cloud.png
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:72)
12-21 15:54:08.350: E/AndroidRuntime(14775):    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It couldn't find the image. Make sure the image is in the correct folder, and the name is spelled correctly:

assets -> data -> monsters -> plant -> gas_cloud.png

If you are sure it is. Then it is probably unsynchronized with eclipse. Click the Android project and hit F5 to refresh it, a clean would be good too. Then try again.